# Is it possible to create an Augmented Reality keyboard in Android using Unity/AR Kit?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, 3d, augmented-reality, arkit

I have been assigned a task to create build an Android application on a mobile phone that has an Augmented Reality keyboard. 
When a user points the phone towards a surface, he/she should be able to view this keyboard on his/her phone and should be able to type in.

This data will then be displayed to the user on the screen.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Mixed Reality Toolkit has a similar solution implemented for HoloLens. You can start by looking into it: https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_SystemKeyboard.html

You can download the project and check the source code from [here.](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/GettingStartedWithTheMRTK.html)

Additionally, using ARFoundation coupled with Unity can give you a jumpstart, where most of the AR functionalities are accessible through the API, like detecting a ground plane to put your keyboard on.